# Flutter: How to implement automatically scroll to content when ExpansionPanelRadio is Expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart

For Example:
i have a list of Custom Object Model like 10 item i display it with ExpansionPanelList.radio and ExpansionPanelRadio then on item 9 and item 10 is out of screen when i pressing on it. it expanded but my screen is not scrolling to that content. how to implement it.

```
getRegisters.when(
  data: (registerModels) {
    final List<RegisterModel>? registerModelsCurrentMax =
        registerModels?.take(currentMax.value).toList();
    if ((registerModelsCurrentMax?.isNotEmpty ?? false) &&
        registerModelsCurrentMax != null) {
      return _buildDataSection(
        registerModelsCurrentMax,
        isLoadingMore,
        scrollViewController
      );
    } else {
      return _buildEmptyDataSection();
    }
  },
  error: (error, stackTrace) {
    return _buildErrorSection();
  },
  loading: () {
    return _buildLoadingSection();
  },
)
```

```
Widget _buildDataSection(
      List<RegisterModel> registerModelsCurrentMax,
      ValueNotifier<bool> isLoadingMore,
      ScrollController scrollViewController,) {
    return Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollViewController,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            RegisterItems(
              registerModels: registerModelsCurrentMax,
             scrollController: scrollViewController,
            ),
            isLoadingMore.value
                ? Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0).w,
                      child: Center(
                        child: LoadingAnimationWidget.waveDots(
                          size: 50.w,
                          color: primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : SizedBox(height: 20.h),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class RegisterItems extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterItems({
    super.key,
    required this.registerModels,
    required this.scrollController,
  });

  final List<RegisterModel> registerModels;
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  State<RegisterItems> createState() => _RegisterItemsState();
}

class _RegisterItemsState extends State<RegisterItems> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10).w,
      child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
        expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.h),
        children: widget.registerModels
            .mapIndexed(
              (index, registerModel) => ExpansionPanelRadio(
                value: index,
                canTapOnHeader: true,
                headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
```

no result i just looking in doc and stack overflow